# How to use AJAX to receive content from Python

Tags: python, html, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX to update a table with data returned from a Python script.  When I request the Python script using AJAX, the returned text is the entire python script file, not just the content in the `print` commands.

My AJAX file:

```
...standard loadXMLDoc function with callback from W3C AJAX tutorial...


function doNow()
{

loadXMLDoc("cgi-bin/get.py",function()
  {
  if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("active_items").innerHTML=request.responseText;
    }
  });
}

window.onload=doNow();
```

For simplicity, I've used python files as simple as:

```
print("<div>something</div>")
```

or

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable(display=0, logdir="/path/to/logdir")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
    print("<div>something</div>")
```

When I load the page, the content of `<div id="active_items">` is:

```
print("
something
")
```

I have already:

- Set the `get.py` file to executable using `chmod 755 get.py`
- Verified that CGI privileges are enabled on my server (i.e. other .cgi scripts work)
- Verified that my AJAX script works with other static files, such as a `.txt` file

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I would love some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the top of your Python file (assumes *nix environment):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If you haven't already, ensure that your web server treats `.py` Python scripts as CGI scripts. An example for Apache is this directive:

```
  <Directory /srv/www/yoursite/public_html>
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
    </Directory>
```

Comment: This worked great!  Question: In some of my trials, my python files began with `#!/usr/bin/python`.  Why didn't that work, but `#!/usr/bin/env python` works?

Comment: If your Python executable is not in `/usr/bin/python` it will not work. `env` uses environment to run whichever python is in the path. In many cases this is better than hard coding the location of the Python executable - it makes your script more portable.